# C#: How do I convert a 3D X Y and Z position to a 2D X and Y position?

Tags: vb.net, math, 3d, 2d, projection

What I would like is some kind of function to convert a 3D position, to a 2D position, e.g.

```
Private Function Get2DPoint(ByRef x As Short, ByRef y As Short, ByRef z As Short)

    Dim newX = x + z '< Some fancy math
    Dim newY = y + z '< Some fancy math

    Dim temp = {newX, newY}
    Return temp

End Function
```

Online resources I have checked but am having trouble understanding (I have not copied information from the pages as they have been up and running for a long time, and there's a lot of information on said pages.):

- [Wikipedia 3D Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection)
- [Visual C# Kicks 3D GDI+ Drawing](http://www.vcskicks.com/3d_gdiplus_drawing.php)

Please don't tell me that I should use a pre-existing library.  I have read a lot of questions on the matter, and using something like OpenGL.  Or other libraries is not what I want to do.

I have been looking for quite sometime now, and I'm really no closer to understanding how to do this, any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

If I forgot to supply any information please let me know, thanks in advance.

Notes:

1. I'm programming in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2015, however it's fine if any examples of code that are given are in: C++, C#, Python, Lua. Or other similar programming languages.
2. I would have liked to post more links, but I don't have the required 10+ reputation.

All the best, Joseph Foote

Comment: What is your 3D position? what do you want the 2D position to represent, the same 3D position projected on a view matrix?

Comment: Ok so lets say my cube is at 0, 0, 0 and each corner is 10 units away from 0, 0, 0. As for the view matrix I'm not really sure what that is, maybe you could explain?

Comment: When observing a 3D object from a certine position there are few things that count, the object's position (your cube for that matter), camera position, camera's look vector, cameras "up" vector, and cameras view angle and ratio. think of it as you are telling me where you are and where the object is standing but you dont tell me if you look directly at it and if you are standing upside down or how big is your eyes field of view.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  The cube will be in front of my camera by about 5 units (0, 5, 0.  I think that is right.).  The angle of the camera will be in this case at an angle of 0, 0, 0.  As for the field of view, I'm not sure what that should be, so lets say about 60?  Also in my case I want to use Z for up and down.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Please tell so next time I can improve upon this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As your [linked example](http://www.vcskicks.com/3d_gdiplus_drawing.php) shows, you need to define a `class` for you cube, a `class` for a point in space, a `class` for your camera and a `class` for rectangle which already exists as `System.Drawing.Rectangle`:

[image: Class Diagram]

*I will not translate the code from C# to VB.net since it can easily be done and that's your job :) but I will explain how it works*

First of all you need to initialize the cube you want to draw, then, you need to define where you want the origin of the 3D space to be located in your `PictureBox`, in your case, lets say you want the middle of the cube which is the (0,0,0) point to be located in the middle of the middle of the `PictureBox`:

```
//Point is also a System.Drawing type.
Point origin = new Point(picCube.Width / 2, picCube.Height / 2);
```

Now all you need to do is to render that picture whenever you like. In this example, the render itself is done within the `Cube` `class` itself, which receives the origin we have just calculated, also in the example ***the Up Vector is always the Y Axis***.

First of all the the method is defined with the following signature:

```
//Gets the origin on the PictureBox to be displayed (middle of the PictureBox).
//Returns the rendered picture.
public Bitmap drawCube(Point drawOrigin)
```

Next, 3 variables are declared:

- A temporary 3D origin.
- A temporary 2D origin.
- An array of 24 2D points to be drawn (the cube will be drawn as 4 quadrilaterals - every edge will be drawn twice - once for every quadrilateral, **this is a bad practice in this example**)

This is the code:

```
PointF[] point3D = new PointF[24]; //Will be actual 2D drawing points
Point tmpOrigin = new Point(0, 0);
Math3D.Point3D point0 = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, 0); //Used for reference
```

Then, the Z position of the camera is defined in relative to the screen resolution in order to keep the cube not messed up:

```
//Screen is another System.Drawing class.
//Called "zoom" in the example.
double baseCameraZ = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 1.5;
```

Next, the points of the cube in space are calculated base on its width, height, and depth (again there are 24 and not 8 since they are drawn per face), and the `cameraZ` position is adjusted accordingly, so that the cube will fit:

```
        //Just filling a 24 length array of Point3D, you can see in the example their exact order.
        //note that the order matters mostly so each face's vertexes will be together in the array - one after another.
        Math3D.Point3D[] cubePoints = fillCubeVertices(width, height, depth);

        //Calculate the camera Z position to stay constant despite rotation            
        Math3D.Point3D anchorPoint = (Math3D.Point3D)cubePoints[4]; //anchor point
        double cameraZ = -(((anchorPoint.X - cubeOrigin.X) * baseCameraZ) / cubeOrigin.X) + anchorPoint.Z;

        //That's the actual camera of the cube - read the example itself for more info.
        camera1.Position = new Math3D.Point3D(cubeOrigin.X, cubeOrigin.Y, cameraZ);
```

The next functions do [transformations over the points using matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearTransformation.html) - ***You do not HAVE to understand how this works but you should probably want to read a little bit about it***, what it does is basically applying the rotation of the cube and positioning it in it's fixed position in the 3D space in relative to the origin:

```
//Apply Rotations, moving the cube to a corner then back to middle
cubePoints = Math3D.Translate(cubePoints, cubeOrigin, point0);
cubePoints = Math3D.RotateX(cubePoints, xRotation); //The order of these
cubePoints = Math3D.RotateY(cubePoints, yRotation); //rotations is the source
cubePoints = Math3D.RotateZ(cubePoints, zRotation); //of Gimbal Lock
cubePoints = Math3D.Translate(cubePoints, point0, cubeOrigin);
```

The next piece of code translate the 3D points of the cube in space to where they belong in the result 2D image, also there is a special check for the case the point falls behind the camera (that's the `if` statement). again, if you want to truely understand it you need to learn some basic [Linear Algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/LinearAlgebra.html):

```
Math3D.Point3D vec;
for (int i = 0; i < point3D.Length; i++)
{
    vec = cubePoints[i];

    if (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z >= 0)
    {
        point3D[i].X = (int)((double)-(vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (-0.1f) * baseCameraZ) + drawOrigin.X;
        point3D[i].Y = (int)((double)(vec.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (-0.1f) * baseCameraZ) + drawOrigin.Y;
    }
    else
    {
        tmpOrigin.X = (int)((double)(cubeOrigin.X - camera1.Position.X) / (double)(cubeOrigin.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * baseCameraZ) + drawOrigin.X;
        tmpOrigin.Y = (int)((double)-(cubeOrigin.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (double)(cubeOrigin.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * baseCameraZ) + drawOrigin.Y;

        point3D[i].X = (float)((vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * baseCameraZ + drawOrigin.X);
        point3D[i].Y = (float)(-(vec.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * baseCameraZ + drawOrigin.Y);

        point3D[i].X = (int)point3D[i].X;
        point3D[i].Y = (int)point3D[i].Y;
    }
}
```

The last thing will be to draw the whole image using `Graphics`:

```
Rectangle bounds = getBounds(point3D);
bounds.Width += drawOrigin.X;
bounds.Height += drawOrigin.Y;

Bitmap tmpBmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmpBmp))
{
    //Back Face
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[0], point3D[1]);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[1], point3D[2]);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[2], point3D[3]);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[3], point3D[0]);

    //Front Face
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[4], point3D[5]);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[5], point3D[6]);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[6], point3D[7]);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[7], point3D[4]);

    //... Four more faces ...
}
```

Now all you need to do is to return the rendered bitmap.

***Note that the design in this example is not necessarily the best, since every object draws itself and is unaware of ZBuffer and other objects in the scene, also, this example uses `int`s instead of `float`s in all of the coordinate variables, which makes you lose a lot of accuracy - this should not be done when working with 3D renderers.***

***[Here is a good source](http://www.riemers.net/) for learning the basics of 3D rendering in C# and C++ with best practices.***